# Is there any way to use a teleporter in Scribblenauts Remix?

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

In Scribblenauts Remix on iOS, I've attempted to use teleporters to solve a couple of puzzles. I make two teleporter pads, but when I try to use one all that happens is the level is restarted. Is this a bug or intended behaviour? Is there something special I need to do to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is the intended behaviour, however silly it may be.  I believe the same thing happens with a *Time Machine* as well as a few other items.  Sorry.

Comment: This is a bad change from the DS version, then!

Comment: @Shinrai actually, I've only played the DS version.  I'm certain that this is how they worked in the original *Scribblenauts* as well.

Comment: They don't instantly restart the level, they take you to a different location, and when you go back through the device the level is restarted.  You can take stuff with you, though.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Mine restarts immediately as well. In sandbox I have supersonic wings, a supersonic rideable dot and a tough lethal zombie too.